# Vaadin + JPA + lazy loading

Tags: jpa, lazy-loading, vaadin

I have Vaadin application backed by JPA. Components in this application are bound to bean properties (via standalone EL implementation). Some of components are bound to external objects (or their fields), linked by @OneToOne, @OneToMany, @ManyToOne and @ManyToMany annotations. The binding performed by implementing com.vaadin.data.Property and setting it as DataSources of components.

The question is: will lazy loading work in "Property"ies if component will be refreshed somehow (by vaadin's ajaxes) after the form is served to browser?

Answer (score 2):

If you have set your PersistanceContext on your EntityManager to PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED then your entities will handle this and hence also vaadin. If you dont have it then you will have to load them manualy.

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "yourname", type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!
But in my case I have to build EntityManager by myself from EntityManagerFactory, so I can't use @PersistenceContext EntityManager.
Maybe I found some kind of solution - I want to read from EntityManager stored in com.vaadin.Application and write using EntityManager that is created every time I need to write something in.

Comment: My last answer is already deprecated. I had to revisit the architecture of db communication code, and had one more try with jpa, this time having EntityManager request-scoped, resulting in generation subsequent SELECT queries on each merge of big object graph. Now I looking towards th jOOQ approach, without JPA at all )